# Undefined References Compiling OpenGL/glfw/glew on Ubuntu(g++)

Tags: opengl, ubuntu, g++, glfw, glew

I am following [this tutorial](http://learnopengl.com/#!Getting-started/Creating-a-window). I `cmake'd` and `make/make install'd` `glfw` and `glew` perfectly(as far as I'm aware). However, when I try to compile the sample code...

```
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main()
{
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

    return 0;
}
```

... using his linker flags...

```
-lGLEW -lglfw3 -lGL -lX11 -lpthread -lXrandr -lXi
```

... I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_init.c.o): undefined reference to symbol 'XF86VidModeQueryExtension'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
```

I Google'd the error and someone suggested adding `-lXxf86vm`. It got rid of the initial error but added a significant number more:

```
/usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_init.c.o): In function `initExtensions':
x11_init.c:(.text+0x1b93): undefined reference to `XineramaQueryExtension'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x1bad): undefined reference to `XineramaIsActive'
/usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_init.c.o): In function `_glfwCreateCursor':
x11_init.c:(.text+0x22ee): undefined reference to `XcursorImageCreate'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x23c5): undefined reference to `XcursorImageLoadCursor'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x23d5): undefined reference to `XcursorImageDestroy'
/usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_monitor.c.o): In function `_glfwPlatformGetMonitors':
x11_monitor.c:(.text+0x743): undefined reference to `XineramaQueryScreens'
```

How do I figure out what flags I need? If it matters this is how my makefile is structured:

```
CC = g++
COMPILER_FLAGS = -std=c++11
FILES = *.cpp
LINKER_FLAGS =   -lGLEW -lglfw3 -lGL -lX11 -lpthread -lXrandr -lXi -lXxf86vm
OBJS = *.o
LINUX_BIN = HelloWindow

#Compile(output into error.txt if there is an error), link, then run
linux:
    $(CC) $(COMPILER_FLAGS) -c $(FILES) 2> "errors.txt"
    $(CC) $(COMPILER_FLAGS) $(OBJS) -o $(LINUX_BIN) $(LINKER_FLAGS)
    ./$(LINUX_BIN)
```

Thanks!

Comment: For GLFW, you probably need `-lGL -lX11 -lXi -lXrandr -lXxf86vm -lXinerama -lXcursor -lrt -lm`

Comment: How did you know what linker flags to use?

Comment: By looking at the unresolved symbols...

Comment: This question is so not a duplicate `:)` I'm grateful it is here, helped me a lot ...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Derhass was correct. The following are the flags I used:

```
-lGLEW -lglfw3 -lGL -lX11 -lXi -lXrandr -lXxf86vm -lXinerama -lXcursor -lrt -lm -pthread
```

Comment: I was also able to use this Answer when working on getting GLFW v2 to compile and link as a static object.

Comment: I also had to add the `-ldl` flag on Ubuntu, and was able to remove the `-lrt` and `-lm` flags. I think it all comes down to what combination of packages/how they're installed, but this list is all-including which is great.